# How can I make a postcard template?

Tags: rules

I would like to print some of my holiday photos as postcards. But sadly, all companies I have seen so far do not offer easy possibilities to create the back of the post card.

So I want to make a template for A6 post cards.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a6paper,landscape,7pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % German umlauts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % German umlauts
\usepackage{hyperref}  % seems to be important for multicols
\pagenumbering{gobble}  % disable page numbering
\usepackage{multicol}  % split page in two parts
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    Skyline of Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania\\
    {\small Photographer: Max Mustermann}
    \columnbreak
    \vspace*{0.5\textheight}
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % Name
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % Street + Nr
    \rule{2.2cm}{0.01cm}\hspace*{0.2cm}\rule{3.4cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % zip code + town
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\\ % country
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

### Rendering

[image]

### Question

The first helping line (commented with `Name`) should get placed on the right side after about half of the page width. But it gets placed on the left side. How can I fix that?

Just in case somebody thinks he can do it, I have a super-duper bonus question: It would eventually be nice to make a small stamp template in the upper right corner. Feel free to adjust anything to make it look nicer :-)
(Usually, I would simply add an image. But there seems not to be any stamp template image on Wikipedia.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key was to add a `\par` before or after the `\columnbreak` to get the line moved over.

Below I give two versions:  without a stamp, and with postage (misaligned and postmarked).

To address the postage, I just placed a `\framebox` of specified size, using `\hfill` to push it to the right margin.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,landscape,7pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % German umlauts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % German umlauts
\usepackage{hyperref}  % seems to be important for multicols
\pagenumbering{gobble}  % disable page numbering
\usepackage{multicol}  % split page in two parts
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    Skyline of Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania\\
    {\small Photographer: Max Mustermann}
    \columnbreak\par
    \hfill\framebox(40,50){\scriptsize Postage}\par
    \vspace{0.25\textheight}
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % Name
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % Street + Nr
    \rule{2.2cm}{0.01cm}\hspace*{0.2cm}\rule{3.4cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % zip code + town
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\\ % country
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get an actual stamp there, I used http://media2.s-nbcnews.com/j/msnbc/Components/Photos/050604/050604_jennystamp_hmed_7a.grid-6x2.jpg and http://www.photojewelrymaking.com/images/products/detail/postmark.jpg and came up with this, making your postcard **extremely valuable** (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_Jenny).

However, it is an obvious forgery, as the postmark pre-dates the stamp by 9 years, and originates in the wrong nation.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,landscape,7pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % German umlauts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % German umlauts
\usepackage{hyperref}  % seems to be important for multicols
\pagenumbering{gobble}  % disable page numbering
\usepackage{multicol}  % split page in two parts
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}\def\stackalignment{r}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    Skyline of Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania\\
    {\small Photographer: Max Mustermann}
    \columnbreak\par
    \hfill\raisebox{3pt}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{postmark}}%
    \stackon[0pt]{\raisebox{8pt}{\framebox(40,50){\scriptsize Postage}}}%
                 {\rotatebox{3}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rarestamp}}~}\par
    \vspace{0.25\textheight}
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % Name
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % Street + Nr
    \rule{2.2cm}{0.01cm}\hspace*{0.2cm}\rule{3.4cm}{0.01cm}\vspace*{1cm}\\ % zip code + town
    \rule{5.8cm}{0.01cm}\\ % country
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Regarding the stamp template: I rather thought of something like this http://www.enchantedlearning.com/crafts/papercrafts/stamp/stamptemplatetiny.GIF or that http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/4/D/A/9/y/blank-postage-stamp-template-dedicated-to-susi-tekunan-by-r-d-miccahofman-md.png

Comment: @moose  That can be done directly in the same manner that I added stamp figures, with an `\includegraphics`, rather than a `\framebox`.